# Getting null values for request scoped bean in Spring boot

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-boot, autowired

I am new to **Spring boot framework** and i need to set Subject bean and print its value in Audit filter.

Following are the classes that i am using:

Subject.java

```
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Subject {

@JsonProperty("cis_uuid")
protected String uid; 

@JsonProperty("token_type")
protected String tokenType;

public String toString() {
    return uid + " "+ tokenType;
}
}
```

MyManager.java

```
public class MyManager {
@Autowired
private Subject subject;

public void SetSubject () {
    subject = getSubject(); // Function return filled Subject bean having both values 
    //Printing subject here prints values for uid and tokenType
}
}
```

Audit.java

```
public class Audit implements Filter {

@Autowired
private Subject subject;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            System.out.println(Subject.toString()); // prints null
}

}
```

FilterConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = "com.org.project")
public class FilterConfig {

@Autowired
Environment environment;

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean oAuthRegistrationBean() {
    final FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    registration.addInitParameter("role", "uc:admin");
    registration.setFilter(new AuthFilter()); //Subject and MyManager are part of this filter
    return registration;
}   

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean avrilAuditFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(getAuditFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    registration.setName("Audit");
    return registration;
}

@Bean
public Filter getAuditFilter() {
    return new Audit();
}
}
```

Getting null values for Subject in Audit filter class which comes in picture after Subject has been set in setSubject() function.

I have two filters Auth and Audit.
First Auth filter comes into picture which sets Subject bean
Secondly Audit filter need to access Subject bean which is **null** in this case

Comment: Can you share complete code along with which Filter you using!!!

Comment: Please include also XML configuration if you are using it.

Comment: I am not using XML config, have added filterconfig file